# How can I use the phrase, "do right by"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammatical-number, british-english

1) How can I use the phrase, "do right by"?

2) And what does it mean exactly when we say that?

3) Can I say, I hope they do right by me? Or I hope he/she does right by me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use this phrase, for example, in talking about how a divorced parent should deal with his ex-spouse for the sake of the children:

> **If you're divorced and have children, you should do right by them and maintain a good relationship with your ex-spouse.**

2. This means that by not fighting with the ex-spouse, you provide a benefit to the children.  It often implies consciously taking a specific action (one you otherwise might not take) in order to bestow some benefit on a third party.
3. Yes, you can certainly follow **do right by** with an object pronoun or any noun.